# How to walk and filter a tree in place?

Tags: c#

Given a tree of complex objects defined by the classes and data below, is there a way to walk the tree in place, applying a filter, such that I'm not cloning my tree objects un-necessarily.

- I have simplified the class for posting purposes, but let's assume that cloning objects in memory will be a burden due to the complexity of the tree nodes.
- This will be called in a multi-threaded environment, so let's assume that assume that removing nodes, or setting properties in the tree itself would cause problems.

I'm not looking for a BFS or DFS traversal, because I would like to keep the tree structure in place.  This

Class:

```
public class Menu
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Menu> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Sample Input:

```
Root
| A1
| | A2
| | B1
| C1
| | A3
| | | A4
| | B2
| D1
| | B3
```

Given a filter for 'A', the desired result should include every node that is either an 'A' itself or contains an 'A':

```
Root
| A1
| | A2
| C1
| | A3
| | | A4
```

I have attempted a view different methods with recursive functions and IEnumerable functions, but I can't figure out how to pass the iterator into the children, without modifying the Menu instance.

```
private IEnumerable<Menu> BuildMenu(Menu menu)
{
    foreach (var i in menu.Children)
    {
        if (/* item is filtered*/)
            yield break;

        // How to pass in current iterator and criteria without NEW()'ing an object?
        yield return new Menu()
        {
            Text = menuWithChildren.Text,
            Children = BuildMenu(menuWithChildren)
        };
    }
}
```

Is this even possible, or are my requirement's invalid?  Thanks for reading.

Comment: How do you want to filter the list without rebuilding each node? Would it be sufficient to have a `Visible` property on each node and set that appropriately?

Comment: don't forget that c# works by reference. ``var object = anotherObject`` only duplicates reference.

Comment: @Jamiec - I don't want to filter the list by removing properties, I want to walk the tree in a way that returns only filtered items.

Comment: No, you misunderstand - A node has a set of children, its not possible to filter that list of children without rebuilding its parent node (`without modifying the menu instance`). I suggested a workaround (and im working on some code for an answer) which just sets a `Visible` property on each node

Comment: Why not build a (small) separete _filtered tree_ with nothing but references to the nodes in the original tree?

Comment: My goal is not to (edit or replace) the list of children, but to build an IEnumerator or some other walking algorithm that would evaluate each node recursively if necessary and return the node (the reference) if it were 'valid'.

Answer (score 1):

In order to filter the list "in place" (ie, without rebuilding the tree/nodes) you could add a property "IsVisible" to each node and set the value appropriately.

In order to pass the filtering logic down, you could use a predicate in the form `Func<Menu,bool>` as a parameter to the filtering function.

Here is a recursive filtering function which will do exactly that:

```
private static bool Filter(Menu item, Func<Menu,bool> predicate)
{
    bool isVisible = predicate(item) ;
    bool isChildrenVisible = (item.Children != null && item.Children.Count(c => Filter(c,predicate))>0);
    item.IsVisible = isVisible || isChildrenVisible;
    return isVisible;
 }
```

It could be called like this:

```
Filter(tree, n => n.Text.StartsWith("A") );
```

I have prepared a live example which demonstrates this: http://rextester.com/GCYV10964

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work in a multi-threaded environment as the Visible flag can be set by two different users, with two different contexts...  Thus my concern with changing the objects.

Comment: Note that due to the way you structured this code it can never short circuit, which means the entirety of the tree always needs to be traversed, when in reality you can stop as soon as any predicate ever returns true as you know that the node needs to be visible.

Comment: @MattMurrell So then force the users to synchronize access to the object.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements you have to maintain immutability. The only way to do that is to create a *View* (or projection) of your initial tree.

The best way is to create a minimal proxy class for the View that only contains a reference to the original menu object

```
class MenuProxy
{
  public Menu Reference {get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<MenuProxy> Children {get; set;}
}
```

and then return it

```
    yield return new MenuProxy()
    {
        Reference = i,
        Children = BuildMenu(i)
    };
```

Here is a complete example

```
private IEnumerable<MenuProxy> BuildFilteredView(Menu menu)
{
    foreach (var i in menu.Children)
    {
        if (/* item is filtered*/)
            yield break;

        // How to pass in current iterator and criteria without NEW()'ing an object?
        yield return new MenuProxy()
        {
            Reference = menuWithChildren,
            Children = BuildMenu(menuWithChildren)
        };
    }
}
```